# ¿De dónde proviene la palabra "vos"?

Tags: voseo

Sé que esta palabra se utiliza mucho en Argentina, para decir "tú", pero me intriga saber de dónde que es que nació dicha palabra.

Ejemplo:

> ¿Hola, cómo estás?
>
> -Bien, Gracias por preguntar. ¿Y *vos* ?

Comment: Este link también puede ser interesante: [voseo](http://www.elcastellano.org/artic/voseo.htm) "Hay que remontar el inicio del voseo español al siglo IV de C. En ese entonces, el empleo del vos en lugar del tú tiene un valor social de sumo respeto. Se ciñe su uso al trato con el emperador. Para su inicio, se apuntan dos causas: una, la presencia de dos emperadores [..] Otros señalan que el vos fue la respuesta al nos, fórmula por la cual el emperador romano se mencionaba a sí mismo, como representante del poder y cabeza de todo el imperio."

Comment: interesante, gracias por tu aporte, y respecto al duplicado... no busqué en inglés, perdón jajaja

Comment: La verdad es que ese duplicado me salió al buscar en google, no sabía que ya teníamos una pregunta similar. Dudé en marcarla como duplicado, por la diferencia de idioma, pero vi que, aunque no con mucho detalle, se trataba el origen de `vos`. Si esa pregunta y sus respuestas no respondiesen por alguna razón a tu duda, dímelo y podríamos reabrir tu pregunta.

Comment: no te preocupes, dicen lo que necesitaba saber :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viene de la palabra latina **vos** que originalmente tenía un significado plural. Su uso ha tenido una historia bastante variada en la lengua castellana, a veces plural, otras singular, en algunos momentos formal, y en otros informal, aunque al final se ha perdurado como un pronombre singular e informal en un número no pequeño de países americanos.

Todavía es posible su empleo reverencial (con conjugaciones diferentes), pero es muy infrecuente, y normalmente reservado a especiosa religiosos.

Comment: !Ojalá que hubieras escrito “la **voz** latina *vos*”! :)